# Printing JSON dict in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary

I have a Tree Species recommender that uses Google maps to select a point, then return the list of Tree Species around it. The original version of this function just printed values from a csv file, but I've adjusted it to search an actual database, average out condition scores, and a lot more. I'm awful with Javascript though, and not sure how to print out the results of my searches.

The dictionary that I'm sending to the page looks like this:

{"species_list": [{"num_trees": 102, "species__trees_of_species__condition__score": 5, "species__id_species": 88, "avg_condition": 5.0, "species__name_scientific": "Arbutus x marina"}, {"num_trees": 828, "species__trees_of_species__condition__score": 4, "species__id_species": 88, "avg_condition": 4.0, "species__name_scientific": "Arbutus x marina"}]}

My current function looks like this:

```
function if_gmap_updateInfoWindow()
    {
    var lng = gmapmarker.getPosition().lng().toFixed(6)
    var lat = gmapmarker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6)
    infoWindow.setContent("Longitude: " + lng + "<br>" + "Latitude: " + lat);
    document.getElementById("location-info").innerHTML = 'Lat / Long: ' + lat + ' x ' + lng;

    // Call the model api
    // TODO consts
    $.ajax({    
        url: '/species-guide/json/' + lat + '/' + lng,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        success:function(response){
            document.getElementById("species-recommendations").innerHTML = response['species_list'].join('<br>')
            console.log(response)
        }
    })
}
```

having "response['species_list'].join('< br >')" prints a list of [object Object] in my species-recommendations tab, but how would I tell it to print the species name and values?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna just show a straight-up JSON string in the DOM, you can do this:

```
document.getElementById("species-recommendations").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response.species_list, null, 2);
```

Important part is: `JSON.stringify(response.species_list, null, 2)`

This will stringify and "prettify" the JSON response, adding line breaks for you, with an indent of 2 spaces.

If you just wanna print keys and values, you'll have to loop recursively through each object:

```
resonse.species_list.forEach(species => {
  Object.keys(species).forEach(key => {
    // place `key` and `species[key]` in some element
  })
})
```

Problem with using "vanilla" JS to do this, is that it clearly is a pain in the ass. Which is why libraries and frameworks (such as Angular) have been invented :)

Comment: I'm still having trouble here, for your '// place 'key' and 'species[key]' in some element, I can't get it to print without reference errors. For example, I would love something like: '<pre>' + species[species__name_scientific] + '</pre><br>'; Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var html = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(response['species_list'], null, '\t') + '</pre>';
```

To have a formated output, you'll need to wrap in `pre` tag.

```js
var response = {"species_list": [{"num_trees": 102, "species__trees_of_species__condition__score": 5, "species__id_species": 88, "avg_condition": 5.0, "species__name_scientific": "Arbutus x marina"}]};
document.getElementById("species-recommendations").innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(response['species_list'], null, '\t') + '</pre>';
```

```html
<div id="species-recommendations"></div>
```